# Why this JQuery Ajax call is not working?

Tags: jquery, simpletest, google-search

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=school',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(msg) {
    alert(""+msg.length);
  },
  error: function (e) {
            alert("Failed to Get declassification details");
        }});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out whats going wrong with this AJAX call.WENT Through several `SIMILAR` question on this forum, but none was working for me.
I have to Get the resultset from Google search in JSON format.

Comment: its giving length as 0(ZERO), Which I guess can be implied as at-least this ajax call has been called.

Comment: JSONP is working, but why so?

Comment: I updated my answer with the basic steps that make JSONP work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is dropping the request because of cross domain security policy.
Try using JSONP (dataType: "jsonp").
Ajax requests to third party websites are normally not possible because of security restrictions. But there are several client-side techniques to work around this restrictions and one of them is JSONP.
One thing you will not get from JSONP is notification of network errors or anything that responds nicely to badly formed responses, so you have to accept that as a tradeoff with the ability to invoke services on other domains.

Why and how JSONP works:

1. Browsers allow you to have a script element get its source from another domain.
2. The requested page is set up do wrap the JSON response in a function call if the name of the function is supplied in a parameter (usually named 'callback') in the url.
3. When dataType is 'jsonp', JQuery creates the wrapping function, adds the callback parameter in the url and inserts a script tag in DOM pointing to the URL you requested.
4. The browser loads the response as a script and executes it, thus calling the JQuery provided function.

See the difference in the response:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=school

vs

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=school&callback=jquery_created_function

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dataType` instead of 'contentType'. Here is code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=school',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("" + msg.responseData.results.length);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("Failed to Get declassification details");
    }
});
```

Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/daay8/1/).

From documentation:

> contentTypeString
>   When sending data to the server, use this content-type.
>
> dataTypeString
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats difference between dataType and contentType. Will this work as usual JSON?

Comment: Thanks for the Great explanation, but why its working with JSONP not with JSON?

Comment: @Sam Rudolph. JSONP is an unofficial protocol that allows making cross domain calls by generating script tags in the current document and expecting a result back to calls a specified callback handler.

Comment: @gor: The Link to the working example is not working any more. Returns Error 404 only.